# What are the differences between Chess and Go from the perspective of computers?

Tags: engines, chess-variants

Please list the differences between the game of Chess and the game of Go for engine programming in a similar format as this one:

Go:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- ...

Chess:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go:

- 3 type of piece on a square (black, white, none)
- huge board (19x19)
- pieces appearing on board
- close to 3^400 possible positions

Chess

- 13 type of pieces on a square (6 black, 6 white, none)
- smaller board (8x8)
- pieces are changing
- less than 13^64 possible positions

Answer (score 2):

Chess:

- Chess programming pretty much consists of optimising the tree search. All attempts at introducing "human like knowledge" into the engines have been dropped for more and more sophisticated search heuristics.
- The ultimate goal in chess programming has been reached. In fact one could argue that chess programming overshot it's goal by a mile or two. Since the mid-2000s no human player stands a chance against the top engines.

Go:

- Apart from searching a search tree of possible variations the latest advances in go programming have included such divers techniques as [Monte Carlo simulations](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Silver/web/Applications_files/grand-challenge.pdf) and [neural networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.3409).
- The best human players are still stronger than the engines, so arguably there is still more to accomplish.

Comment: This answer was valid when written, but computers have since beaten humans at Go. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlphaGo_versus_Lee_Sedol